# Flash in the HTML5 Soundcloud Widget?

Tags: html, flash, soundcloud

We make use of the **Soundcloud HTML5 Widget** (referenced here: http://blog.soundcloud.com/2012/01/26/html5-widget/) and it appears that a call to *soundmanager2_flash9.swf* has made it's way into the widget (possibly to display and manage the new artwork?).

Why is there a Flash file loaded into HTML5 player?  Are we missing something?  Please advise.

Comment: You are not missing something, due to implementation of HTML5 audio, we are still using Flash for playback on browsers that have Flash. Mark Knol has written a proper short summary of the reasons right below. We have created http://areweplayingyet.org to find out how soon the browsers' implementation gets good enough and to let the browser vendors know what is expected from them.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is used as fallback for the implementation of the sound API of modern browsers. This API is not finalized and does not work consistent over all browsers. Some parts of html5 could be considered as sort of beta and if you want cross-browser experience, you need to hack fallbacks. Older browsers never had the native ability of playing sound, however Flash supports playing sounds since the early days of its excistance on the web.